# Using a response from an actor in current actor process

Tags: java, akka, completable-future, akka-cluster, akka-typed

I am confused about how I should resolve this scenario in a non-blocking manner.

Consider two actors `Actor1` and `Actor2`

Within `Actor1`

```java
Map<Int, Int> foo() {
     List<String> finalList = foo_2();
     Map<Int, Int> finalMap = // do stuff with finalList to get Map<Int, Int>;

     return finalMap;
}

List<String> foo_2() {
    
     CompletableFuture<List<String>> Querylist = ask(Actor2)
     Querylist.get();
     
     return QueryList;
}
```

Currently within foo_2, `Querylist.get()` is a blocking call. I want to somehow resolve this in a non-blocking manner. I created a message adapter for `Actor2` inside `Actor1` so any messages that `Actor2` sends will be handled by `Actor1`.

I used the following approach to modify the blocking call

```java
Map<Int, Int> foo() {
     CompletionStage<List<String>> finalList = foo_2();
     finalList.whenComplete(
        // what to do here? 
     )
     // Map<Int, Int> finalMap = // do stuff with finalList to get Map<Int, Int>;

     return finalMap;
}

CompletionStage<List<String>> foo_2() {
    
     CompletionStage<List<String>> Querylist = ask(Actor2)
     
     
     return QueryList;
}
```

I am not sure how to correctly use the CompletionStage construct to get the same result I was getting with a blocking futures.get() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Akka Typed (implied from the tag), you shouldn't need a future or a message adapter at all.  Just use `ActorContext.ask`.

See the [documentation for request-response with ask between two actors](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#request-response-with-ask-between-two-actors).

Broadly, you'd get rid of the `foo` and `foo_2` methods, move the message adapter you've set up into the `ActorContext.ask` call, and replace the instances where you've previously called `foo` with a call to `ActorContext.ask`.  If the reply your actor sends to the message which led to the ask depends on the response to the ask, then a good practice is to embed the required portions of state into the message the adapter generates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is what I ended up doing. Would you know what is the difference between doing a .tell() vs using ActorContext.ask()? Is the difference that you are passing the "handler" explicitly in ActorContext.ask() ?

Comment: The ask ultimately does all the work of managing the request-response interaction for you: it's built on top of tells (more or less everything in Akka is, after all).  Broadly, ask spawns an actor and injects a reference to that actor as the reply-to address in the message to send.  When that actor receives a message, it executes the adapter and forwards the adapted response to the actor which sent the ask; that actor also schedules a message to itself for after the timeout expires which it transforms into the timeout message.

Comment: Because it spawns an actor for receiving the reply, it's marginally less efficient than registering a message adapter, doing a tell, and scheduling a timeout message to yourself.  However, you can have arbitrarily many asks with different adapters in flight: with tell + adapter, you may hit the limit of one adapter per type (registering a different adapter for the same type may be unpredictable and inheritance may also play havoc with this approach).  The tell + adapter approach does have the advantage of allowing multiple replies.

Comment: That clears up a lot. Do you know roughly, how significant the overhead is?

Comment: Can you also help me out with another question.- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69725512/messages-from-cluster-singleton-dropping-en-route

Comment: The overhead is negligible: a few hundred bytes of memory consumption and probably a microsecond or so extra latency in getting the reply to the asker.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pipeToSelf`, see https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#send-future-result-to-self, to send the result of the ask to the actor itself. Instead of trying to get the value for `finalList` directly in foo(), which is only possible with a blocking `get`, the result of foo() can be sent to the actor itself, in which case you handle it like any other message. It's good practice to create a specific message type for this.

You should also have a look at `CompletionStage` methods, most importantly  `thenApply` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenApply-java.util.function.Function-) which makes it possible to transform results, for instance to create a `Map` from the `finalList`, and for instance a `MapMessage` from the `Map`. You would then handle the `MapMessage` like any other message in the actor.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. Ultimately I went with the accepted answer since it seems more idiomatic.